# Connecting Excel to PostgreSQL via VBA

Tags: excel, postgresql, vba, odbc, ado

Is it possible to make query like `SELECT` from VBA in Excel, so I can query a PostgreSQL DB from Excel?

If is possible please explain me how to connect to the database. I was looking in Google but found no results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a table or view in PostgreSQL that describes the data you want.

Use an ODBC or ADO connection from VBA to connect to PostgreSQL. If using ODBC you'll need to create a DSN via `odbcad32.exe` then use the DSN in VB, it isn't easy to just connect directly.

See:

- [Using ADO in VBA to connect to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117516/using-ado-in-vba-to-connect-to-postgresql)
- [PostgreSQL Query to Excel Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5509460/398670)
- http://jackdebear.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/connecting-to-postgres-from-excel.html
- [Enabling import/export flows between a remote postgres database and excel workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351487/enabling-import-export-flows-between-a-remote-postgres-database-and-excel-workbo)
- [Does ADO work with ODBC drivers or only OLE DB providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187811/does-ado-work-with-odbc-drivers-or-only-ole-db-providers)
- [How to put query results into a datatable with Excel VBA and ADO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204688/how-to-put-query-results-into-a-datatable-with-excel-vba-and-ado)

[Better written eample that uses Oracle](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/how-to-query-oracle-from-excel-2007/), but the principles are the same - ODBC/ADO.

Answer (score 8):

Here's some code can use as reference. Hope it helps.

```
Sub SelectBasic()

        Dim objDb_con
        Dim strSomeValue As String

        Set objDb_con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Set Rsdatatype = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

        glbConnString = Trim(ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value)
        //Connection string format:Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Database=MyDB;server=192.16*.*.**;UID=USERID;Pwd=pasword //comment it
        If glbConnString = "" Then
         MsgBox "Enter the Connection String"
        Else:

        objDb_con.Open glbConnString

        strSql = "select strSomeValue  from SOMETABLE where Something=1"
        Rsdatatype.Open strSql, objDb_con, adOpenKeyset, adLockpessimistic
        If Rsdatatype.EOF = False Then strSomeValue = Rsdatatype.Fields(0).Value
        Rsdatatype.Close

        End If
        objDb_con.Close
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Even for 64-bit Windows, Excel VBA needs the [32-bit ODBC driver](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/).

Create a DSN via `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`. Indeed, typing `odbcad32.exe` points towards the 64-bit version where you can't find the proper 32-bit drivers by default.

Source: https://github.com/windweller/postgresql-excel-addIn

Comment: @Craig's answer (which is good and has more detail than yours) already points out the 32bit issue. Do you really add any value to it with this answer?

Comment: Actually, I **couldn't** connect Excel to PostgreSQL via VBA with Craig's answer, nor with all the other answers on StackOverflow. None mentioned the potential problem with `odbcad32.exe`.

It may be obvious to some but not for me and, by the number of unanswered threads on the web, I guess I am not alone. The Excel add-in on Github doesn't work due to a format problem but the wording is excellent to explain the procedure to follow.

If you don't want to publish my answer, I will not be mad but several people will encounter the same problem just like me in the future.